# >> SyntaxError: Unexpected token : Warning: Task "default" not found

Tags: gruntjs

i have this tasks in gruntfile.js

and when I run: grunt default
Loading "gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR

> > SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
> >     Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

i don't find where is the error in my code.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    //uglify
    uglify: {
      options: {
        mangle: false,
        compress: {
          drop_console: true
        }
      },
      js: {
        files: [{
          cwd: 'assets/javascripts/',
          expand: true,
          src: '*.js',
          dest: 'assets/javascripts/min/'
        }]
      }
    }
 });


  sass: {
        // this is the "dev" Sass config used with "grunt watch" command
        dev: {
            options: {
                style: 'expanded',
                // tell Sass to look in the Bootstrap stylesheets directory when compiling
                loadPath: 'assets/stylesheets/sass/'
            },
            files: {
                // the first path is the output and the second is the input
                'sass/main.css': 'assets/styleheets/sass/main.scss'
            }
        },
        // this is the "production" Sass config used with the "grunt buildcss" command
        dist: {
            options: {
                style: 'compressed',
                loadPath: 'assets/stylesheets'
            },
            files: {
                'sass/main.css': 'assets/stylesheets/sass/main.scss'
            }
        }
    },
    // configure the "grunt watch" task
    watch: {
        sass: {
            files: 'sass/*.scss',
            tasks: ['sass:dev']
        }
    }
});
 // loadNpmTasks
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

 // Run Default task(s).
grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify', 'watch', 'buildcss']);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your definitions are not nested properly, you should move `sass` and `watch` inside the `grunt.initConfig` block, and move `grunt.registerTask, grunt.loadNpmTasks` directives to the end of the `function(grunt) {}` block, like that:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
         uglify: {},
         sass : {},
         watch : {}
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify', 'watch', 'buildcss']);
};
```

see [Sample Gruntfile](https://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile)